# Is it possible to create an IRC server with a server from a webspace hoster?

Tags: irc

I'd like to create an IRC server, and I've registered for free webhosting at bplaced.net, and I'm wondering if it is possible to run a server there. Can I do it, and if yes, how?

Comment: FWIW: If you don't know how to host an IRC server and the technical requirements thereof, it's probably going to be a massive failure. Further, it's free hosting, they provide minimal features (you get what you pay for). I'd highly suggest getting familiar with IRC server administration first, preferably with a server running on your machine that's not accessible to the outside world.

Comment: Note that many shared hosting and even dedicated providers do not permit IRC servers per their Acceptable Use Policy.  Be sure to check that you can in fact run an IRC server on their network.

Comment: I am guessing your host provided will be very upset with you if you even start to get any traffic on that. I suggest setting an IRC Server up on a home machine till you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an IRC server with a server from a webspace
>   hoster?

Well there's no real term 'webspace hoster' but there are lots of hosting companies that offer services perfectly capable of running an IRC server on yes.

That said the one you link to don't seem to offer actual code execution services, I've only glanced at their FAQ but they seem to just be a file sharing and DB management hoster - I certainly couldn't see any references to what kind of operating environment they offer which would imply they don't offer one.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as a web hoster AND a 20 year IRC Admin veteran I can say the answer is definitely "maybe".

1. Unless the TOS/AUP forbids IRC, you aren't violating policies if you do.
2. IRC server software (daemons) have to be compiled so you need ssh access and compiler access. Many hosts, I'm one of them, do not allow access to a compiler to users on servers I have configured as web hosting only.
3. Many hosts, again, I do this too, charge extra for irc server hosting so you may ruffles some feathers by trying to host  an irc server without permission.
4. If you try to link to an experienced IRC network, they will know if your server is on a cheap machine or not and many will not allow you to link.
5. As mentioned, it's an excellent idea to know how IRC works before being an admin on a public server. This is so you can properly respond to a crisis.
6. If you have broadband at home (cable/DSL), you can host a small server at home if you only want to learn with a few friends.

IRC server hosts are very cheap, there are many for $5/mo USD or less. None of the big networks will allow you to link to them if you have no "real world" experience and it's best to have a good quality server even though it's more expensive.

The Ideal environment for an IRC server is on a machine that has 1GB of RAM or more, single core 2.2Ghz or more, 100MB of disk space or more and 10mbit unmetered bandwidth or more with DDoS protected IP's (DDoS Mitigation).

Answer (score 1):

The most hosters dont accept any IRC servers. I think the best way is to ask the hoster himself and check out the way to run an irc server.